# C++ second invocation of eagerly evaluated coroutine ovewrites first output

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

I have a following code where I want to pass lambda or any other invocable object into an awaiter to call it at `await_suspend()`. Using `co_await` while using `void(int)` works properly, however, when I try to get a return value from a returning coroutine using `co_return` by using eager evaluation, the program does not behave as expected, however while using lazy evaluation, everything works correctly. However, both attempts cause `Invalid read by size 4`. AFAIK everything is done by the documentation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

#define DEBUG(x) std::cout << __FILE__ << ": " << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << __LINE__ << ": " << x << std::endl

// set lazy evaluation by uncommentting this line
//#define LAZY

/* create nonvoid task that will return value from coroutine through the promise_type */
template <typename RET>
struct nonvoid_task {
  struct promise_type;
  using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  handle_type coro;

  /* coroutine with handler */
  nonvoid_task(handle_type cr) : coro(cr) {
      DEBUG("Creating non void coroutine");
  }

  /* destructor, no destroyign of handler here */
  ~nonvoid_task() {
      DEBUG("Destroying coroutine");
  }

  /* get return value from the coroutine handler */
  RET get() {
      DEBUG("Return value");
      DEBUG(std::hex << &(coro.promise().result) << std::dec);
#ifdef LAZY
      coro.resume();
#endif
      return coro.promise().result;
  }

  /* promise type which is used to return the value using co_return */
  struct promise_type {
    RET result;

    /* get return object */
    auto get_return_object() {
        auto task = nonvoid_task{handle_type::from_promise(*this)};
        DEBUG("get_return_object(): " << std::hex << &task << std::dec);
        return task;
    }

    /* set initial suspend to either lazy or eager eval */
#ifdef LAZY
    std::suspend_always initial_suspend() {
#else
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() {
#endif
        DEBUG("");
        return {};
    }

    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept {
        DEBUG("");
        return {};
    }

    /* get return value to the member result */
    void return_value(RET v) {
        DEBUG("Setting return value " << std::hex << &result << std::dec << " to " << v);
        result = v;
    }

    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};

/* template returning nonvoid_task that takes separate arguments */
template <typename RET, typename F, typename ... ARGS>
nonvoid_task<RET> ret_test(F to_invoke, ARGS ... args) {
    DEBUG("Not tuple");
    co_return std::invoke(to_invoke, args...);
}

int main() {
    /* function returning int for nonvoid_task */
    auto ret_func = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };

    /* invoke coroutines through overloaded templates */
    auto A = ret_test<int>(ret_func, 42, 2);
    auto B = ret_test<int>(ret_func, 42, 3);

    /* get value from coroutine A and B and print it */
    std::cout << A.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << B.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Not only that coroutine A and B print 126 and 126, instead of 84 and 126, they even share same address of `coro.promise().result`, which should not happen according to documentation. This does not happen when using lazy evaluation.

Valgrind output:

```
==36893== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==36893== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==36893== Using Valgrind-3.17.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==36893== Command: ./a.out
==36893==
test.cpp: nonvoid_task: 21: Creating non void coroutine
test.cpp: get_return_object: 46: get_return_object(): 0x1ffefff5b0
test.cpp: initial_suspend: 56:
test.cpp: ret_test: 78: Not tuple
test.cpp: return_value: 67: Setting return value 0x5b3ac90 to 84
test.cpp: final_suspend: 61:
test.cpp: nonvoid_task: 21: Creating non void coroutine
test.cpp: get_return_object: 46: get_return_object(): 0x1ffefff5a8
test.cpp: initial_suspend: 56:
test.cpp: ret_test: 78: Not tuple
test.cpp: return_value: 67: Setting return value 0x5b3ad00 to 126
test.cpp: final_suspend: 61:
test.cpp: get: 31: Return value
test.cpp: get: 32: 0x5b3ac90
==36893== Invalid read of size 4
==36893==    at 0x401576: nonvoid_task<int>::get() (test.cpp:36)
==36893==    by 0x400BC9: main (test.cpp:91)
==36893==  Address 0x5b3ac90 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==36893==    at 0x4C2DB0C: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:802)
==36893==    by 0x400F73: ret_test(nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int)::_Z8ret_testIiZ4mainEUliiE_JiiEE12nonvoid_taskIT_ET0_DpT1_.frame*) [clone .actor] (test.cpp:80)
==36893==    by 0x400CF1: nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int) (test.cpp:77)
==36893==    by 0x400BA7: main (test.cpp:87)
==36893==  Block was alloc'd at
==36893==    at 0x4C2B751: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==36893==    by 0x400C89: nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int) (test.cpp:80)
==36893==    by 0x400BA7: main (test.cpp:87)
==36893==
84
test.cpp: get: 31: Return value
test.cpp: get: 32: 0x5b3ad00
==36893== Invalid read of size 4
==36893==    at 0x401576: nonvoid_task<int>::get() (test.cpp:36)
==36893==    by 0x400BEE: main (test.cpp:92)
==36893==  Address 0x5b3ad00 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==36893==    at 0x4C2DB0C: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:802)
==36893==    by 0x400F73: ret_test(nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int)::_Z8ret_testIiZ4mainEUliiE_JiiEE12nonvoid_taskIT_ET0_DpT1_.frame*) [clone .actor] (test.cpp:80)
==36893==    by 0x400CF1: nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int) (test.cpp:77)
==36893==    by 0x400BBD: main (test.cpp:88)
==36893==  Block was alloc'd at
==36893==    at 0x4C2B751: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==36893==    by 0x400C89: nonvoid_task<int> ret_test<int, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int>(main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, int, int) (test.cpp:80)
==36893==    by 0x400BBD: main (test.cpp:88)
==36893==
126
test.cpp: ~nonvoid_task: 26: Destroying coroutine
test.cpp: ~nonvoid_task: 26: Destroying coroutine
==36893==
==36893== HEAP SUMMARY:
==36893==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==36893==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 72,800 bytes allocated
==36893==
==36893== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==36893==
==36893== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==36893== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*I want to pass lambda or any other invocable object into an awaiter to call it at await_suspend().*" This sounds rather dubious. If `await_suspend` is supposed to resume something, that "something" ought to be a coroutine, which it would simply return the handle of. What are you trying to do with all this?

Comment: @NicolBolas This is just an example of coroutine's capabilities and it's modifications. This code is used only to learn how this stuff works. My next goal is to write a wrapper for coroutines which will encapsulate that hideous boilerplate code which is required by coroutines.

Comment: Coroutines already encapsulate their "hideous boilerplate". You have to write the boilerplate *once*, and then you just `co_await` on those types. "*This code is used only to learn how this stuff works.*" You really shouldn't fling code at a language construct to see how it works. You should have a usage scenario and apply the language construct to most effectively accomplish that.

Comment: Just as a random comment, you don't need to use a macro for the debug statement. You can get all the same data from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

> ```
> std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept
> ```

A coroutine basically looks like this:

```
Type actual_coroutine(args)
{
  promise p;
  initial-suspend-point;
  { /*Body of coroutine*/ }
  final-suspend-point;
}
```

"Body of coroutine" is the body of code you put into your coroutine, where `p` is the promise object for your coroutine.

As you can see, the final suspend point happens outside of the coroutine body. But it also happens in the same scope as `p`.

But note that there's *nothing* after the final suspend point. So, what happens when a function runs out of stuff to do?

It ends, returning control to the caller. But also, all of the stack objects in its scope *are destroyed*.

Objects like `p`; your promise. So by the time you call `get`, the promise object it tries to talk to *has been destroyed*.

Oops.

As such, if you want to access your promise object after the coroutine effectively ends (and in your case, you do), you *must not use* `suspend_never`. You should use `suspend_always` instead.

Not suspending at the final suspend point is mainly for things like generators, which may not need the promise after they flow off the end of the coroutine.